# Has some other jQuery plugin replaces jFeed for parsing RSS now that jFeed is no longer maintained?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, rss, xml-parsing, jfeed

I was trying to find a jQuery plugin to parse an RSS feed and found that jFeed was the most recommended option for quite some time but judging by the broken links on its plugin page and the fact that it hasn't been updated since 2008, I'm guessing this is no longer the state-of-the-art in jQuery RSS parsing.

Could anyone recommend a more up-to-date alternative or point to a fork of jFeed that is still maintained by someone else?

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of jQuery RSS plugins:

- [zRss](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/zRSSFeed)
- [SimpleRSS](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jq-simplerss)

And several others:  http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/rss

Answer (score 2):

Now the project is manteined at github: https://github.com/jfhovinne/jFeed.
Not so much active, but not that bad.

And there are several forks you can look at too. 
For example, https://github.com/invernizzie/coffeed is a CoffeeScript version of the same plugin.